# Disable indexing encrypted field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am storing an encrypted field in my elastic search index but do not want to search by it, I just want this field to be stored in the document and returned when queried by other fields.
Can I disable search just for this one string field ?

motivation: Indexing time has become multifold after addition of this field and looking to reduce the time and space the index takes.

Comment: Thank you upvoted!

Comment: Great thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `index: false` and `store: true` option for this field.

`Index: false` will not index the field and will not be searchable(true by default) and `store: true` means it will be stored but not be queryable.

Please refer [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) and [store](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) option in Elasticsearch for more details and examples.

Also, you can avoid storing the source of all fields by disabling the `_source` options and `index:true` only on the fields which require search to speedup your indexing process.